# IPv6 on Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, ipv6

I have an Azure VM and it works fine with IPv4

Tried to directly associate IPv6 to it, but couldn't connect to the outside world, a simple `ping ipv6.google.com` hung (according to Microsoft, it is impossible, but with a load balancer is possible)

Then, with a load balancer (Standard), I have associated an IPv4 and IPv6 to it but the problem persists, maybe I don't know how to configure one properly. This is what I did:

- Created inbound rules (for HTTP(S), SSH and 8080)
- Created outbound rule with Fronted IP as my IPv6, pool as my IPv6 pool and default allocation of ports

Changed back to the setup where I have the VM with both IPv4 and IPv6 attached.

My VM needs to be able to connect to an IPv6 server, someone can give some help?

Comment: Does Azure even support IPv6 in VM instances?

Comment: Yes it does, I can connect to my VM using http://[ipv6]/ being ipv6 the public ipv6 of my VM

Comment: Did you actually connect to the VM or to the load balancer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attached both IPv4 and IPv6 to the VM without a load balancer and created the rules in the NSG to allow traffic to get in and out (I allow everything in and everything out), and test with another server.

Because I wasn't able to ping anything, I used netcat.

On the server I wanted to test, I executed `nc -6 -l 8080` and on the VM `nc -6 IP 8080` and sent a message. The server got the message, so I know I could connect to IPv6.

I just had to change VNet and Network Interface to support IPv6 and attach the IPs to the network interface.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below steps in below source by using azure shell

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ipv4-ipv6-dual-stack-standard-load-balancer-powershell

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ipv4-ipv6-dual-stack-standard-load-balancer-powershell

Seems like the solution is based on using load balancer

The subnets for IPv6 must be exactly /64 in size. This ensures future compatibility should you decide to enable routing of the subnet to an on-premises network since some routers can only accept /64 IPv6 routes.

**And it has some limitations**

•IPv6 for Azure virtual network is available in all global Azure Commercial and US Government regions using all deployment methods.

•ExpressRoute gateways CAN be used for IPv4-only traffic in a VNET with IPv6 enabled. Support for IPv6 traffic is on our roadmap.

•VPN gateways CANNOT be used in a VNET with IPv6 enabled, either directly or peered with "UseRemoteGateway"

•The Azure platform (AKS, etc.) does not support IPv6 communication for Containers.

•IPv6 can be load balanced only to the primary network interface (NIC) on Azure VMs. Load balancing IPv6 traffic to secondary NICs is not supported.

•IPv6-only Virtual Machines or Virtual Machines Scale Sets are not supported, each NIC must include at least one IPv4 IP configuration.

•When adding IPv6 to existing IPv4 deployments, IPv6 ranges can not be added to a VNET with existing resource navigation links.

•Forward DNS for IPv6 is supported for Azure public DNS today but Reverse DNS is not yet supported.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried the steps in the links, but I couldn't do anything, but thanks, I got my problem solved

Comment: thanks if it was helpful please mark it solved